# How to compile Oracle package with APEX functions?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, plsql-package

I am trying to compile an Oracle package that my colleague left to me. However, the package spec. contains some functions that may not be built in my Oracle environment.

```sql
create or replace PACKAGE AAA IS
  g_session     VARCHAR2(400) := v('SESSION');
  g_user        VARCHAR2(400) := v('APP_USER');

  PROCEDURE p_1;
END AAA;
```

When I try to compile the package spec in Oracle developer, I states

> `'V' must be declared.`

Since the colleague that left me this code is no longer available, I have no idea of how to compile them.

Comment: I am thinking if `v` is some Oracle built-in functions or provided some Oracle library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `v` function is meaningful in Apex environment; it'll return the value of the parameter you pass to it. In your example, that would be something like this:

```
v('SESSION') = 32604633949883   --> session ID
v('APP_USER') = LITTLEFOOT      --> user logged to Apex
```

Apart from Apex environment, the `v` function works from your named PL/SQL stored procedures, packages and such.

As you aren't capable of compiling that code, it seems that there's no Apex installed in the database that contains that package. Is there? If not, well, you won't be able to compile it so you can:

- install Apex, or
- remove the `v` function calls from your code

Comment: How can I tell if my Oracle instance has APEX installed? Actually I find some settings about APEX in some scripts.

Comment: Connect as a privileged user and run `select * from all_users order by username` - APEX users will be listed somewhere at the top of the list.